# NFS booted Pi hangs if booting while the server is not ready

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config, nfs, cmdline.txt

I'm NFS booting a Pi and using DHCP IP assignment wonderfully well.  I've noticed that in the event of a power outage or other situation that interrupts the connection to the server, the Pi freezes and needs to be manually restarted.  Also if the Pi happens to power up and it cannot reach the DHCP server or if the NFS server is not available then it will hang.

Is there some way that the Pi can be configured to boot from NFS but to fail back to a local image or reboot if it can't make, or looses a connection?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "freezes", but this seems to be a linux issue rather than a hardware / pi one. It would help to know which distribution you use and if you have changed any configuration / added stuff yourself

Comment: I'm using a current and rather stock Raspbian install.  I agree that it is a Linux issue.  It will stop responding and do nothing until the power is cycled.  If the Pi can't find the DHCP of NFS server on boot it will eventually attempt to boot from a floppy but otherwise just hangs indefinitely waiting for a disk.  I'm wondering if there is some way to co-opt that functionality to boot an emergency image on the SD card that could simply reboot the Pi after a predetermined amount of time.  That way, maybe eventually if would make contact with the server and boot properly.